# Deep Learning in Spark Clusters vs on GPUs?

Tags: deep-learning, apache-spark, performance, gpu

What would be a better way to perform deep learning on any given task,
either using Spark Clusters or by taking advantage of GPU's multiple cores.

Which would give less training time and be better way to go about?

Comment: Is there a reason why there can't be GPUs in your Cluster?
If the question is **what's better, CPU or GPU?**, surely GPU is the right answer, since it can deliver more FLOPs. After all, I think it highly depends on what your cluster consists of.